# get src information and insert it in css3 content - tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i don't really know how to insert the src information of a html tag into the css3 content tag.

for example:

get

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" controls> 
<source src="63f01c0300d2848a.webm" type="video/webm">     
 <p> Your browser doesn't support WebM video.</p> 
 </video>
```

and insert it in

```
  <style type="text/css">
  #videoname:after{content:"";}
  </style>
```

i know how to start, but i have not enought knowledge about js..

```
function notEmpty(){
 var srcname = document.getElementById("video").src;
if(srcname.value != "")

else    
??insert ("no video selected")??    }
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: You didn't define `id` attribute in your `source` element.

Comment: so put that in the question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do with Jquery,
Add this code to your `<head>`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
<script>
var source = $('#source').attr('src');
$('#videoname').html('<b>&gt;&gt; ' + source + '</b>');
</script>
```

and add id="source" to your source tag

```
<source id="source" src="63f01c0300d2848a.webm" type="video/webm">
```

and put this div wherever you want:

```
<div id="videoname"></div>
```

Updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/x32pb/2/

Comment: this looks perfect, but the src information have to be in the header behind two ">>" and this doesn't really work, i hope you can help me with my code (:? http://jsfiddle.net/x32pb/1